# mysql find out two row inserted after each other

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to find out that two row inserted after each other ?

i have table like this :

table1

```
 ID   |     column1                 |     column2 |
    ---------------------------------------------
 1    | '2013-11-04 13:47:03'       |       A     |
 2    | '2013-11-04 13:47:03'       |       B     |
 3    | '2013-11-04 13:47:13'       |       Y     | 
 4    | '2013-11-04 13:47:13'       |       X     | 
 5    | '2013-11-04 13:47:20'       |       B     |  
 6    | '2013-11-04 13:47:23'       |       Z     |
 7    | '2013-11-04 13:47:23'       |       X     |
 8    | '2013-11-04 13:47:26'       |       X     |  
 9    | '2013-11-04 13:47:26'       |       Z     |
 10   | '2013-11-04 13:47:35'       |       B     | 
 11   | '2013-11-04 13:47:38'       |       A     |
 12   | '2013-11-04 13:47:38'       |       B     | 
 13   | '2013-11-04 13:47:40'       |       A     | 
 14   | '2013-11-04 13:47:41'       |       X     | 
 15   | '2013-11-04 13:47:41'       |       Z     |
```

in the above table i want find the The exact Time when "A,B" happen after each other , Like "A" be the first and next row after that "B" happen . 
Then i save the DateTime of "A" for starttime.

after that i check for when "X,Z"  happen like above , and this "X,Z" must be after time "A,B" happen and save "Z" time for endtime.

then i get average of time between start and endtime.

Comment: Please reconsider your table structure. This doesn't make too much sense in my eyes. The basic use of ID and `auto_increment` would probably be enough in this case.

Comment: @RobinCastlin yes table have autoincreament and id, ill fix the table now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an automatic `TIMESTAMP` column set to have the default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on insert. With this column you can always see when a record has been created.

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

It is very common practice in most applications to have a `date_created` and a `date_updated` column on tables with time-relevant information (blog: articles, comments, users; ecommerce: products, carts, orders, invoices, customers).

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `date_updated` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```